# Form that has a date picker input. And I’m sending my data to the database using nodejs

Tags: node.js, sql-server, datepicker, momentjs

My problem is: when I set the data type of my date picker to just “date” my data makes it to the database(even though it’s not the current date), BUT when I set the data type of my date picker to “datetime-local” it doesn’t make it, instead it’s just giving me an error.

1. [Date picker image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tbhzt.png)

```
    <form action="/formdata" method="POST"class="row g-12 needs-validation" novalidate>
            <div class="row"> 
               <div class="col-md-4">
                     <label for="inputState" class="form-label">End Shift</label>
                      <div class="form-group"> <input name="datepicker" id="datepicker" 
                        class="form- 
                       control" type="datetime-local" required> </div>
               </div>
            </div>
```

2. This is how I'm adding the data to the database (SQL Server)

```
    class forms {
        constructor(datepicker,site,line,units){
    
            this.d = datepicker;
            this.s = site;
            this.l = line;
            this.u = units;
        }
        
    }    
    
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());    
    
    //make directory static
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));    
    
    //we getting the home.html page 
    app.get("/",(req,res)=>{
        res.sendFile(__dirname+"/public/home.html");
    });    
    
    //creating a route for form data 
    app.post("/formdata",(req,res)=>{
        const userDetails = new 
         forms(req.body.datepicker,req.body.site,req.body.line,req.body.units);
        
        //Requesting database 
        var request = new sql.Request();
    
        // let datetime =userDetails.d ;
        console.log(userDetails.d);
     
        const date = moment(userDetails.d).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
    
        // Insert data into the database 
        let mssql = (`INSERT INTO DataEntry(Date,TimeStamp,Line,Units,Site) 
           Values(${date},'25114','${userDetails.l}','${userDetails.u}','${userDetails.s}');`);
    
           request.query(mssql,function (err, data) { 
               if (err) throw err;
               console.log("User data is successfully inserted"); 
          });
            res.sendFile(__dirname+"/public/home.html");
    });

    //Listern to port 3002
    app.listen(port,(e)=>{
        if(e) throw e;
        console.log("html page provided");
    });
```

3. This is the error I'm getting

> originalError: Error: Incorrect syntax near '11'.

4. This is the date format on my database

[Databasecolums and data format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFW1i.png)

5. And this is how the date appears in my database when when the date picker datatype is set to "datetime-local".

[Date entry to the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNTEi.png)

As you can see things look pretty broken, please help me figure out this problem.

Comment: That's because you're not inserting a date into your query, you're inserting a string without enclosing `'` characters. You should learn to use Prepared Statements and [Parameterized Queries](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#input-name-type) or one day you'll have a [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) situation on your hands.

Comment: ` Values(${date},` is going to resolve the something like `Values (2021-08-06 10:34:47,` which would give `Incorrect syntax near '10'`. Date literals are wrapped in single quotes (`'`)` but instead don't do that and **parametrise** your query; your code is dangerous and has a significant security vulnerability.